# Google Analytics for Apache Cordova Application

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am not able to implement the google analytics for my Apache Cordova application.As of now I am concentrating on Android platform which gets me only

-The number of users currently using the app.

-Geo location of the current users.

Please let me know which Plugin should I use and how to get the solution for requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `com.analytics.google` plugin. The step by step explanation is as below:

1. Install the plugin

   cordova plugin add com.analytics.google
2. Initialise the analytics in app:

   `// If android and analytics plugin is present`

   `if(window.analytics) {
       window.analytics.startTrackerWithId('Your analytics code');
     }`
3. Create methods to track clicks, page views etc.